# dompdf 0.6 renders much larger pdfs

Tags: dompdf

I upgraged from dompdf 0.5.2 to 0.6.0 beta3, the same html, rendered to pdf is now 3-4 times the filesize they were previously.

I have played with all the config vars, and nothing seems to make them smaller.

NOTE: I have NO external fonts, only specified font is helvetica. The config file does list the "default_font" as "serif", but changing that to helvetica has no effect on filesize.

Is there another reason this update would make so much larger pdfs? 
What is a better tool to convert html to pdf?

Comment: This could be due to changes in how images are processed. It would help to see a sample HTML document.

Comment: The upgrade process specifies that you must remove any existing font metrics and replace dompdf_config.inc.php with the new one. Did you double check the upgrade is valid.

If that fails there is a host of tools to help debug the issue, perhaps this can help you out, http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php

There is a ton of useful information on the WIKI.